# Clicking on router_link in angular-8 app causes page postioning issues

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

When i click on any router_link in angular-8 app that page opens but page first goes down in footer then I refresh, it comes on header section.

I have tried some functions like `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` but it didn't work for me.

What I actually want is, as I open any page it opens by the header section not by the footer section.

Answer (score 0):

we can use **{ scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' }** on eagerly loaded modules or just in **app.module** and it will be applied to all routes. **RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' })**